# Flutter:Expanded generated blank

Tags: flutter

I want to know how this gap is generated, although it looks pretty

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBgUn.png)

Expanded It seems that the height is set automatically. Is there any regularity in this height? How to remove

This is a form consisting of cloumn and row, the textfield is in the row, and is wrapped by Expanded

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage("img/phone_icon.png"),
                  width: 36.w,
                  height: 19.h,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                Text(
                  "+60",
                  style:
                      TextStyle(color: Color(0xff666666), fontSize: 15.sp),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.w, 0, 14.w, 0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  width: 1.w,
                  height: 12.h,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffCCCCCC)),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff666666),
                      fontSize: 15.sp,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: S.of(context).phoneNumber,
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFCCCCCC),
                        ),
                        border: InputBorder.none),
                    inputFormatters: [
                      WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10)
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                    cursorColor: Color(0xFF1FA2FF),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
         ......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contentPadding` in input decoration to adjust the height of TextField Input

```
....
TextField(
    InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Search users",
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 15.0,
        )
)
....
```

[Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/contentPadding.html)